# Mobile Device Management and Configuration Profiles

Tags: mobile-device-management, configuration-profiles

I have two questions about Mobile Device Management Server and Configuration Profiles.
We are using a Third Party MDM server where we are registering our devices to have control of the apps that are running on our organization

When we deliver the Configuration Profile over the MDM server on a freshly restored device we are seeing that some apps are not being hidden (like Facebook, Whatsapp and some others). They only hide if we reinstall or update that apps, there are some kind of configuration that we can made to block these apps?

The second question is about the icon arrangement before we uninstall the Configuration Profile. Once the profile was removed we notice that the icons are rearranged in a new order that doesn't like the old arrangement (before the blocking). There ara some action that we can do to keep the order of the icons?

Thanks!